# Android Custom LockScreen

Tags: android, widget, lockscreen

I want to create a custom lockscreen widget in android for my news application which will show highlights in a listview on lockscreen. How do I start? I want a layout like this application:
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.doublelabs.androscreen.echo&hl=en

Thanks,

Comment: This question is way too broad. Stack Overflow is about helping solving *specific* problems.

Comment: Check out the api examples that come with the sdk, you'll probably find something in there that will point you in the right direction

Comment: You could build a regular widget, since API 10 (if my memory is correct), users can put screen widgets on their lockscreen. Not sure it's what you're looking for tho.